# MySQL can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

I know there are similiar posts here but I didn't find the appropriate to my problem yet.

In an MySQL table oxarticles I have articles imported from an external program. The program sends each article twice as parent article and as variant with some columns containing additional data.

I want to normalize the table, writing the additional column data into the parent article.

My update query looks as follows:

```
UPDATE  oxarticles
    SET     oxean = (SELECT oxean FROM oxarticles WHERE oxparentid = oxid),
            oxstock = (SELECT oxstock FROM oxarticles WHERE oxparentid = oxid),
            oxinsert = (SELECT oxinsert FROM oxarticles WHERE oxparentid = oxid)
```

while the parents oxid is bound to the column oxparentid of the child/variant.

Unfortunately I receive the error:

```
Your can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause
```

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE oxarticles a 
    LEFT JOIN oxarticles b ON a.oxid=b.oxparentid
SET a.oxean =b.oxean,
    a.oxstock  =b.oxstock ,
    a.oxinsert  =b.oxinsert
```

Comment: Thank you. This leads into the error "oxean cannot be null" because "oxarticles a LEFT JOIN oxarticles b ON a.oxid = b.oxparentid" selects parent articels too. I think this is an issue with MySQL not letting me update data from and within the same table. I am looking further.

Comment: @BernhardKraus : I would think that this because one of the oxid do not have a parent and because oxean is not nullable you get this exception. You could always try to change the left join to a join. But then the rows that do not have a parent will not be update. But maybe that is expected?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Here is my solution.

```
UPDATE  oxarticles a
    SET     a.oxean = ( SELECT oxean FROM ( SELECT oxean, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1),
            a.oxstock = ( SELECT oxstock FROM ( SELECT oxstock, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1),
            a.oxinsert = ( SELECT oxinsert FROM ( SELECT oxinsert, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1),
            a.oxsubclass = ( SELECT oxsubclass FROM ( SELECT oxsubclass, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1),
            a.oxsort = ( SELECT oxsort FROM ( SELECT oxsort, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1),
            a.oxvarname = '',
            a.oxvarstock = 0,
            a.oxvarcount = 0,
            a.oxvarminprice = 0.00,
            a.oxvarmaxprice = 0.00
```

Just fyi:

```
 AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%'
```

just identifies a certain data type within the tables data. In my case it is possible that there are articles with real variants. These must not be touched by the update process so I only select articles containing the string "GrLos" in column "oxartnum".

Since MySQL doesn't support udate operations within the same table yet you have to force MySQL to create a temporary table. That's what we have to do with the subselects in the set operation:

```
SET a.oxean = ( SELECT oxean FROM ( SELECT oxean, oxparentid, oxartnum FROM oxarticles) tmp WHERE tmp.oxparentid = a.oxid AND tmp.oxartnum LIKE '%GrLos%' LIMIT 0,1)
```

In case there are more than one variantes to an article I limit the subselect result to 1

```
limit 0,1
```

Perhaps this may help other people in the future.